# HTACCESS issue please let me know what I am doing wrong

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to rewrite this url but nothing work please let me know what I am doing wrong..
I need to rewrite the URL so the only thing to see is the keyword plase help

```
chopo.com.mx/promocion?codigoPromo=2&region=2&keyword=Perfil-Hormonal-1

Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## hide .php extension snippet

# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([0-9]+)/$ http://chopo.com.mx/promocion.php?codigoPromo=$1&region=$2&keyword=$3

# To internally forward 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]

# To remove www header
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: What's wrong with `chopo.com.mx/promocion?codigoPromo=2&region=2&keyword=Perfil-Hormonal-1` and what do want to be rewritten as?

Comment: I need to have it rewrited as chopo.com.mx/promocion/perfil-hormonal-1  but the htaccess is just ignoring the rule

Comment: You may have more success if you title your question less generically.

Answer (score 0):

Keep your code like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## hide .php extension snippet

# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L]

# To remove www header
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f    
RewriteRule ^promocion/([\w-]+)/?$ promocion.php?codigoPromo=2&region=2&keyword=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

# To internally forward 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: still not working, I thought it could be as the variables are numeric, but besides that I dont understands why is not working.. please see: http://chopo.com.mx/promocion.php?codigoPromo=2&region=2&keyword=Perfil-Hormonal-1

Comment: What happens when you enter URL as: `chopo.com.mx/promocion/perfil-hormonal-1` in browser?

Comment: now it works however wont load the styles. pretty close thank you

Comment: use absolute path in your css, js, images files rather than a relative one. Which means you have to make sure path of these files start either with `http://` or a slash `/`.

Comment: I appreciate your help a lot, it worked nicely but since I am working with variables they are not properly appiled to my other results, it only worked with that specific one but if I need to use other variables for example: codigoPromo=3&region=3&keyword=$1  and many other they wont work, also my variables are not loaded into the comboboxes you can se in the link http://chopo.com.mx/promocion/Perfil-Hormonal-1